# How to run xUnit tests in special order

Tags: xunit

How can I run my xUnit tests in a special order?

I use [this sample](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/TestOrderExamples/TestCaseOrdering) but it doesn't work!

I want to a `Fact` run first and then rest of the tests run.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a way...